# Pay Pal IPN Status

Tags: paypal-ipn

Zen Cart's pending unilateral Pay Pal IPN status is unchanged, after changing primary email address in Zen Cart. How do i get pending status to change to complete? Pay Pal still has no record of the order or funds.